# Database to CRUD application, Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, crud

I have a fairly large DB schema and about 100M rows with I would like to expose to the web, using Rails 3. By exposing to the web, I mean the following:

- A REST api (json & xml)
- Views to present the data hierarchically
- Editors for specific parts of the data

Basically, what I am looking for is a way to run the rails scaffold command with the appropriate arguments automatically. I know that magic_model can do some parts of the reverse engineering itself, but it does not seem to be working with Rails 3.

Is there any tool that can automate the generation of scaffolding?

Answer (score 3):

You could give the following gems a try:

- [ActiveAdmin](http://activeadmin.info/)
  -> Though more of admin framework, it has an appeasing user interface and will aptly satisfy your scaffolding needs.
- [ActiveScaffold](https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold) -> A simple auto-scaffold generation framework

Comment: ActiveAdmin is beautiful indeed. But does it offer an API in addition to the generated web pages? ActiveScaffold looks closer to what I was looking for when I asked the question, but from browsing its (scarce) documentation I could not see its advantages over the regular rails scaffold command. For example, it will not look into the database to extract relationships between the models. magic_model did this.

Comment: I don't think ActiveAdmin offers a REST api :( But, you could always do that with ActiveResource. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html

Answer (score 0):

I just changed a bit a script of mine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'active_record'
require 'active_support'
require 'logger'

require 'fileutils'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(YAML::load(File.open('database.yml')))

ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(File.open('database.log', 'a'))



for table in ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables  

  table_class=table.classify
  eval("class #{table_class} < ActiveRecord::Base;set_table_name \"#{table}\";end")

  columns = []
  for column in Kernel.const_get(table_class).columns
      columns << "#{column.name}:#{column.type}"
  end

  puts "rails generate scaffold #{table_class} #{columns.join(' ')}"

end
```

I tried it on a database of mine (I use only mysql) and I think its output is quite good. Basically it prints the scaffold commands. I don't know if it is a good solution for you but it's a fair starting point IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reverse_scaffold. It does what the name implies, i.e. Automatically creates the scaffolding from existing table in the legacy database.

You can find it on github:

https://github.com/chrugail/reverse_scaffold (rails 3 version)

There is also a rails 2 version by ahe (the original author)